# Concise Introduction to Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, galois-theory

I'm looking for a short, concise introduction to Galois Theory (but please don't assume I know anything about Galois Theory). I don't want a complete and "fat" Bourbaki-style book.

My main motivation is to be able to read this pdf about Galois Schemes : http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf because it look very interesting especially the connection between Topology, Algebraic Geometry and Galois Theory.

I just know basic facts about fields, and I followed one semester of commutative algebra (in the book of Atiyah-MacDonalds).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concise classic is [*Galois Theory*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndml/1175197041#toc) by Emil Artin.

[image]

Comment: @Ihf: This is a little out of date now. I remember the "field" used in the book is not assumed to be commutative, for example.

Answer (score 2):

A more recent "concise introduction" is Ian Stewart's "Galois Theory". Very pleasant to read.

Comment: That is clearly not concise.

Comment: Well, Galois theory is not an elementary matter.  Would you tsay that Artin or Rotman are more concise ?

Comment: Artin's book is clearly more concise, so are the first editions of "Classical Galois Theory" by Lisl Gaal - the most recent edition, though, has gained some weight.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo Can I ask you that how does Stewart vs. Rotman or Morandi? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A very good one is **Galois Theory** by *J.Rotman*. There is a very good introduction at the beginning of fields and rings, a very detailed appendix about the group theory, and a very good introduction to Galois Groupe et Galois theorem.

Comment: I know the books by Artin, Rotman and Stewart. I prefer Stewart's, which I find easy and pleasant to read, and I have even used it to teach a course in Galois theory. I don't understand the reproach "not concise" from Alex M. because, as I said, after all, Galois theory is not an elementary matter. The most concise introduction I know is chapter 1 of Kaplansky's "Fields and Rings". But  conciseness is not necessarily good for beginners.